# Simultaneous pan and zoom with Android MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is it possible to handle simultaneous zoom **and** pan events using a `MapView`?

The Google Maps app for Android allows the map to be panned while a pinch-to-zoom gesture is already underway. This is helpful for making fine adjustments while you zoom in on a region of the map. The default `MapView` does not seem to support this.

I am prepared to implement this functionality myself, but I would prefer to use the built-in mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using an `Overlay`. By overriding the overlay's `onTouchEvent()` and detecting when zoom and pan events happen, those events can be handled in parallel.

For anyone facing this problem, I have posted a [sample project based on my solution](https://github.com/acj/PinchPanMapView/).

**EDIT**:

The new [Google Maps v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) library supports simultaneous zoom and pan. Unless there is a need to customize the event handling algorithm, I strongly recommend upgrading to the new library.

Comment: How does the new library support simultaneous pan and zoom? I'm making calls to `moveCamera`, and when I do one `moveCamera` using `scrollBy` (panning) and then another `moveCamera` using `zoomBy` (for zooming), they appear to "fight" each other and only the second move seems to take effect?

Comment: Sorry, my question was about simultaneous pan and zoom based on touch events from the user. I think you might be able to use `animateCamera()` to solve your problem, though - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13936465/357055).