# Android Google Maps v2 - set zoom level for myLocation

Tags: android, google-maps-mobile, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to change the zoom level for myLocation with the new Google Maps API v2?

If you set `GoogleMap.setEnableMyLocation(true);`, you get a button on the map to find your location.

If you click on it, then the map will bring you to your location and zoom it in to some level. Can I change this zoom to be less or more?

Comment: do you have any idea of mylocation button zoom level? I want that value.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

It's doubtful you can change it on click with the default myLocation Marker.  However, if you would like the app to automatically zoom in on your location once it is found, I would check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739990/map-view-following-user-mylocationoverlay-type-functionality-for-android-maps/13753518#13753518)

Note that the answer I provided does not zoom in, but if you modify the onLocationChanged method to be like the one below, you can choose whatever zoom level you like:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if( mListener != null ) {
        mListener.onLocationChanged( location );

        //Move the camera to the user's location and zoom in!
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 12.0f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful using `animateCamera()` in your `onMapReady()`, this may lead map lag with lite yellow background. For map init it is better to use `moveCamera()` (same signature)

Answer (score 164):

You can also use:

```
mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 17.0f ) );
```

To just change the zoom value to any desired value between minimum value=2.0 and maximum value=21.0.

The API warns that not all locations have tiles at values at or near maximum zoom.

See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#zoomBy%28float,%20android.graphics.Point%29) for more information about zoom methods available in the `CameraUpdateFactory`.

Comment: What is the default zoom level??

Comment: 14 is the default zoom level

Comment: Why did you choose `17.0f`?

Answer (score 33):

with location - in new GoogleMaps SDK:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(chLocation,14));
```

Comment: Is there a difference between newLatLngZoom() and zoom() which a lot of other answers have referenced? In app, from end user perspective, these look the same.

Answer (score 24):

Here are the [approximate zoom levels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#zoom) and what they do :

```
1: World
5: Landmass/continent
10: City
15: Streets
20: Buildings
```

so you could do something like this to zoom to street level for example (note the "15f" below is street level) :

```
 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
    googleMap?.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
    googleMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
            .position(LatLng(37.4233438, -122.0728817))
            .title("cool place")

            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)))

    googleMap?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(37.4233438, -122.0728817), 15f))
```

note: just so you know different locations can have different max zoom levels.  try to use `googleMap.maxZoomLevel` if you want to get the max or min zoom levels.

Answer (score 15):

Slightly different solution than HeatfanJohn's, where I change the zoom relatively to the current zoom level:

```
// Zoom out just a little
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(map.getCameraPosition().zoom - 0.5f));
```

Answer (score 14):

In onMapReady() Method

change the zoomLevel  to any desired value.

```
float zoomLevel = (float) 18.0;
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to write only one line in maps_activity.xml

```
map:cameraZoom="13"
```

I hope this will solve your problem...

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even i recently had the same query....some how none of the above mentioned setmaxzoom or else map:cameraZoom="13" did not work 
So i found that the depenedency which i used was old 
please make sure your dependency for google maps is correct
this is the newest use this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

`mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPlace,15));`
This is will not have animation effect.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with "mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 17.0f ) );" but it didn't work for me. So I used this animation for zooming in on start.

```
LatLng loc = new LatLng(33.8688, 151.2093);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("Sydney"));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 18), 5000, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Location locaton;
double latitude = location.getlatitude;
double longitude = location.getlongitude;
```

If you want to save the zoom or get it all the time,you just need to call the following

```
int zoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

//To set that just use

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(getlatitude(), getlongitude),zoom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers above are either deprecated or the zoom works by retaining the current latitude and longitude and does not zoom to the exact location you want it to. Add the following code to your **onMapReady()** method.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //Set marker on the map
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0.0000, 0.0000)).title("Marker"));
    //Create a CameraUpdate variable to store the intended location and zoom of the camera
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(0.0000, 0.0000), 13);
    //Animate the zoom using the animateCamera() method
    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```