# How to set static zoom limit google map v2 android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to set static zoom limit for google map v2.I don't want the user to be able to zoom out/in map.

Comment: which google map version are you using?

Comment: I'm using google map version 2

Comment: I think this can solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932441/android-google-maps-v2-set-zoom-level-for-mylocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this -

1)  To give static zoom level -

```
map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(xxxx,xxxx) , 14.0f) );
```

2) For disabling zoom control -

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Okay then, post it as answer please.

Answer (score -1):

```
map.getUiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

The zoom controls (`setZoomControlsEnabled`) affects the on-map "+" and "-" while `setZoomGesturesEnabled` affects gestures like pinch to zoom or double-tap