# Android Google Maps Zoom not to right Location and Activity Crash when high frequently open and close

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've got a problem with the mapMapfragment of GoogleMaps in Android.

I used this Method, which have to be override:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    gm = googleMap;
    gm.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.choose_festival_gps_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        gm.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    gm.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude(), longitude())).title(name()));
    gm.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude(), longitude())));
    gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

}
```

Then I called this one in an Async Task:

```
((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(Activity.this);
```

Now I got two problems, I've searched for a long time but got no clue how to solve it:

1. The Map zoom is not exactly to my location, maybe 5 km northern of it.
2. If I open and close the Activity high frequently, I've got the following Fatal Exception.

   > java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

**1. The Map zoom is not exactly to my location, maybe 5 km northern of it.**

You can check on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932441/android-google-maps-v2-set-zoom-level-for-mylocation). It advised to add a `LocationSource` to your GoogleMap and respond to `onLocationChanged` events. You can check the sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753518/5832311).

**2. If I open and close the Activity high frequently, I've got the following Fatal Exception.**

Maybe you are attempting to find a fragment before it exists. Or maybe you're trying to get at the map fragment from inside another fragment in the fragment's `onCreateView()` method. It was stated in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991087/mapfragment-getmapasyncthis-nullpointerexception). You can also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27613370/5832311) that you might encounter that error if you are using specific version of Google Play Services but  the Gradle build select the most recent version.